# Convert columns of an Excel into dictionary in python

Tags: python, excel, dictionary, xlrd

I have three columns in my excel file, i have to convert all the rows of the first two columns into a dictionary using xlrd.

Expected Output:

```
{'Sam' : 'Tester', 'John' : 'Developer', 'Fin' : 'Tester'}
```

[image: screenshot of Excel file]

```
for i in range(1, worksheet.nrows):
    row = worksheet.row_values(i)
    variable = row[0] + row[1]
    print(" {0} {1}".format(row[0],format(row[1])))
    print(variable)
```

The code prints the first two columns. How to convert to dictionary type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First thing, dictionary are enclosed in {} not [] so the expected output should be `{'Sam' : 'Tester', 'John' : 'Developer', 'Fin' : 'Tester'}`

This code should work for you:

```
my_dict = {}
for i in range(1, worksheet.nrows):
    row = worksheet.row_values(i)
    my_dict[row[0]] = row[1]

print(my_dict)
```